Is Ripley 8 the Newborn’s Grandmother and Father?
At the start of Alien Resurrection (1997), we see Ripley 8 receive a caesarian section:  A Chestburster is removed and contained, and she is sewn back up.
Later, we learn that the scientists have a Queen Xenomorph in their custody.  This makes Ripley 8 the Queen’s mother.  She even describes it as “her baby” when talking to Call.
Near the end of film, Ripley 8 is pulled down through the floor into the Queen’s lair.  She is seen writhing in it’s tentacles (or whatever you’d call that); getting rather casual:


After a change of scene and back, the Queen is preparing to birth the Newborn creature.
Cocooned above, Dr. Jonathan Gediman remarks:

I told you, at first everything was normal; the Queen laid her Eggs.  But then she started to change; she added a second cycle, so….  So,…, this time there is no host, there are no Eggs, there is only her womb and the creature inside.  That is Ripley’s gift to her, a human reproductive system.  She is giving birth for you Ripley.  And now she is perfect!

Was the scene pictured above really supposed to be Ripley 8 siring the abomination? — That would make her both the Newborn’s Grandmother and Father, right?
And if that isn’t right, what is Ripley 8 doing in that scene with the Queen? — I’m not sure how else to interpret it.
What exactly is the biological relationship between Ripley 8 and the Newborn?

They're both clones of the original Ripley, hence all the failed Ripley clones and alien clones.

Parasitic gestation hosts don't count as parents.

Grandmother (rather host as DavidW states) and witness to birth (not even midwife, let alone father). Not sure the aliens have fathers per se.

Any clues as to what “details or clarity” I need to add to my question to get it reopened?

The problem, as I see it, is that you're already aware that Ripley didn't directly birth the Alien. It arose as a parasite from their mixed DNA when she was cloned, and was then removed from her before it killed her.
